# Function passing some arrays when generating links for a menu

Tags: php

I am trying to generate the links for a menu

I have a json file with the references and i'm trying to generate the menu

I am using this function called `dnd` for debugging

```
function dnd($data) //debug function
{
 echo '<pre>';
 var_dump($data);
 echo '</pre>';
  die();}
```

I have this function :

```
  public static function getMenu($menu)
  {
  $menuAry  = [];
  $menuFile = file_get_contents(ROOT . DS . 'app' . DS . $menu . '.json');
  $acl = json_decode($menuFile, true);
  foreach($acl as $key => $val)
  {
    if(is_array($val)) {
      $sub = [];
      foreach($val as $k => $v) {
        if($k == 'separator' && !empty($sub)) {
          $sub[$k] = '';
          continue;
        }else if($finalVal = self::get_link($v)) {
          $sub[$k] = $finalVal;
        }
      }
      if(!empty($sub))
      {
        $menuAry[$key] = $sub;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if($finalVal = self::get_link($val))
      {
        $menuAry[$key] = $finalVal;
      }
    }
  }
  return $menuAry;
}
```

And the get_link function looks like :

```
private static function get_link($val) {
  //check if external link
  if(preg_match('/https?:\/\//', $val) == 1) {
    return $val;
  } else {
    $uAry = explode(DS, $val);
    $controller_name = ucwords($uAry[0]);
    $action_name = (isset($uAry[1]))? $uAry[1] : '';
    if(Self::hasAccess($controller_name, $action_name)) {
      return PROOT . $val;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

And if i'm trying to `dnd` the acl before the foreach , i'm getting this :

```
 array(6) {
  ["Home"]=>
  string(4) "home"
  ["Tools"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["My Tools"]=>
    string(5) "tools"
    ["Tool 1"]=>
    string(11) "tools/first"
    ["Tool 2"]=>
    string(12) "tools/action"
    ["separator"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Tool 3"]=>
    string(11) "tools/third"
  }
  ["Google"]=>
  string(23) "https://www.google.com/"
  ["PHP Docs"]=>
  string(25) "https://php.net/manual/en"
  ["Login"]=>
  string(14) "register/login"
  ["Logout"]=>
  string(15) "register/logout"
}
```

And i don't know why it skips the Tools part , as i get this at the end , as it should add the `/framework/` at beginning as `ROOT` is `\framework\` and it skips tools and the last , i've looked at the youtube guide 10 times and downloaded the source , but nothing seems to fix it

```
array(3) {
  ["Home"]=>
  string(15) "/framework/home"
  ["Google"]=>
  string(23) "https://www.google.com/"
  ["PHP Docs"]=>
  string(25) "https://php.net/manual/en"
}
```

`acl.json`

```
{
  "Guest" : {
    "denied" : {},
    "Home" : ["*"],
    "Register" : ["login", "register"],
    "Restricted" : ["*"]
  },
  "LoggedIn" : {
    "denied" : {
      "Register" : ["login", "register"]
    },
    "Register" : ["logout"],
    "Tools" : ["*"]
  }
}
```

`menu_acl.json`

```
{
"Home" : "home",
"Tools":
  {
    "My Tools" :"tools",
    "Tool 1" :"tools/first",
    "Tool 2" :"tools/action",
    "separator" :"",
    "Tool 3" :"tools/third"
  },
  "Google" :"https://www.google.com/",
  "PHP Docs" :"https://php.net/manual/en",
  "Login" :"register/login",
  "Logout" :"register/logout"
}
```

Comment: please add some info about the context. It seems to me that you are using some framework/CMS or something like that? Alos, since you are citing a video and the added code, please provide a link there.

Comment: @Beppo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QM2TGRAbNqI&list=PLFPkAJFH7I0keB1qpWk5qVVUYdNLTEUs3&index=46

Comment: It looks to me that the problem lies somewhere in some code you did not post, most probably in the hasAccess function, which seemingly returns false for the tools and register entries. Also, if you are on windows: Take into account the comment of user741 on youtube: you need to replace `DS` by `'/'`as URLs and the json description of the menu always use `/` as a directory/element separator, but windows does not.

Comment: @Beppo this fixed my login , thank you , but my tools still doesn't work

Comment: I assume that you are not granted access to the `tools` part by hasAccess function. Pleas ad it to the post so i can check it.

Comment: @Beppo added at the bottom

Comment: @Beppo add it as reply so i can give ya the rep .. i wasn't conected , i am so dumb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(as discussed in the comments)

There were two seperate problems:

- in the example from the youtube video, the dev used the global `DS` for splitting the array entries into controller and action, but this only works on linux/unix hosts, where the directory seperator `/` is the same as the one used in the json site description. The split has to be done by a plain `'/'` (as user741 pointed out in his comment at youtube)
- access to the `tools` options is granted only for logged in users and it was therefore not listed.

Such things happen to me all the time, that is why so many people like doing pair programming - much more likely for a single person to fixate his thinking to one approach than for two people to both fixate on one and the same ;-)